# Error 404 with Slim api in sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

this is my folder structure

```
channel
   - includes
      - db_connect.php
      - functions.php
   - libs
      - vendor
      - composer.json
   - v1
      - .htacces
      - index.php
```

this is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

I am new to all this and i dont really understand the .htaccess file or what it does. when i try to connect using the url

```
http://localhost/channel/v1/index.php/test
```

I get a 404 error. This is the block of code am using to get the test parameter

```
$app->post('/test',function(){
    echo 'test is working';
})
```

How do i get this to work properly? Am doing all this in ubuuntu

Answer (score 0):

With slim (or most other REST Services), you don't call your methods using `WEBROOT/index.php/yourdefinedEndpoint` but `WEBROOT/yourdefinedEndpoint`. For `$app->post('/test',function(){});` it should be `http:// localhost/channel/v1/test` (also note: if you define a post route but call the page as GET (without a form), there'll be an error. For learning, try `$app->get('/test',function(){};`

The .htaccess file basically rewrites all "subfolders" to parameters, which the Slim Framework will parse for you and call the matching function.

EDIT: Please note you'll need to have .htaccess enabled (see the [ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles) ) and mod_rewrite (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache)).

Additionally, I'd recommend using the .htaccess provided by the Slim Documentation